# How do I feed an array of worksheet names into VBA Sheets.Copy?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, copy, worksheet

I have this code that populates an array with worksheet names, given a condition:

```
Dim lng_Counter As Long    
Dim arr_wks() As Variant

lng_Counter = 1

For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Left(wks.Name, 2) = "Hi" Then
        ReDim Preserve arr_wks(lng_Counter)
        arr_wks(lng_Counter) = wks.Name
        lng_Counter = lng_Counter +1
    End if
Next wks
```

I would then like copy these worksheets to a new workbook and so I have tried something like this:

```
Sheets(arr_wks()).Copy
```

Which isn't working. The only way I can get it to work is to write out:

```
Sheets(Array(arr_wks(1),arr_Wks(2),...)).Copy
```

Which isn't useful as the size of the array will change depending on the number of sheets that meet the condition at a given time.

How can I feed the array into a Sheets(arr).Copy type argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You end up with an error where the first element (with an index of zero) is empty.

You can fix that with

```
lng_Counter = 0
```

, or

```
ReDim Preserve arr_wks(1 to lng_Counter)
```

, or

```
Option Base 1
```

on top.

Comment: Do you mean lng_Counter = 0? I used the ReDim Preserve arr_wks(1 to lng_Counter) solution. Thank you.

Comment: @jakrooster Yes, I did.